# Is A New Instance of an Already Verified Contract Considered Already Verified

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, testnets, contract-verification

While testing some deployment and verification scripts, we deployed a smart contract and verified it on testnet etherscan.

Then redeployed the smart contract again and tried to verify the new contract address on etherscan.

The verification failed with `Reason: Already Verified`.

Is verification not related to every new contract instance?

Grateful for any insight on this.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that reason because it can't be right. Changed contract code and different deployment address. Makes no sense. Wonder if the problem is on localhost preventing it from reverifying.

Comment: @sola Thanks for the response! It's not changed contract code. Same contract code on a different deployment address. Will this cause it to return already verified?

Comment: ah. yes. in that case yes it's fine. it's just another instance of the same. you should be able to see the contract source code at the new deployment address on etherscan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases, Etherscan is able to match the newly deployed bytecode to contracts that were verified earlier (if the contract code didn't change). They do this "auto-verification" to expand the list of verified contracts even if developers didn't verify everything.

I've found that it doesn't *always* automatically verify duplicate contracts, especially when deploying to multiple networks. So it's still a good idea to include the verification step in your workflow, even if you'd expect it to get auto-verified.

To make verification an easy part of your workflow you should use either [truffle-plugin-verify](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) (created by me) or [hardhat-etherscan](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan) / [hardhat-deploy](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy) depending on which framework you use.